# Pandas count category frequency in a row

Tags: python, pandas

The questions I see here are all about groupby and count by columns.
If I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
       a       b      c      d      e
0    Apple    0.3    Pear   0.4    Apple
```

I want to count the category frequency of these certain columns: [a,c,e] for each row and create a column for the most frequent category.
In this case it would be column f, value of "Apple" since it has 2 occurrences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `mode`

```
df['f']=df.loc[:,list('ace')].mode(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
```